# Is the following pairs of set are homeomorphic?

Tags: general-topology

Is the following pairs of set are homeomorphic ?

the set$ S^1 = \{z \in \mathbb{C} | z = e^{iθ},0 ≤ θ < 2π\}$ and $A =\{z \in \mathbb{C} | z = re^{iθ} , 
1 ≤ r ≤ 2, 0 ≤ θ < 2π\}$ with their usual topologies inherited from
 $\mathbb{C}\simeq \mathbb{R}^2$.  where C is complex is  field.

i was trying to visualise this  question, but i could not able to find out whether they are homeomorphism... but from my point of view  both they are homeomorphic because they both are one-to-one...

If anybody help me, i would be very thankful to him...

Answer (score 4):

No, they are not homeomorphic. Remove any $2$ points form $S^1$ and it becomes disconnected. Remove any $2$ points form $A$ and it remains connected.

Comment: im not getting @ jose carlos santos,,,,,remove any two point from A remain connected

Comment: @lomberlego The set $A$ is an [annulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annulus_(mathematics)). Look at the picture. It is connected and if you remove any finite set from it, it is still connected.

Comment: thanks @ jose carlos santos

Comment: @lomberlego If my answer was helpful, please mark it as the accepted one.

Answer (score 1):

Another proof that they are not homeomorphic is to consider a small circle in $A$, such as $t \mapsto \frac{3}{2} + \frac{1}{10} e^{it}$ where $t\in [0,2\pi)$. It is a continuous non constant closed curve that is one to one but not onto. Such curves don't exist in $S_1$.

In order to answer @JoséCarlosSantos 'doubts, here is a detailed argument:
    if $F \colon  A \rightarrow  {S}_{1}$ is a homeomorphism, then the map
    $z \mapsto  F \left(\frac{3}{2}+\frac{1}{10} z\right)$ is a continuous map from
    ${S}_{1}$ into itself and it is one to one. It is not onto because
    $F \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)$ is not reached. This is a contradiction because
    of the following theorem, which I prove below

**Theorem**
(Gribouillis) If $f \colon  {S}_{1} \rightarrow  {S}_{1}$ is continuous and one to one, then it
is also onto and it is a homeomorphism.

**Proof**
Let ${\varphi} \colon  \mathbb{R} \rightarrow  {S}_{1}$ be the continuous map ${\varphi} \left(t\right) = {e}^{i t}$. Let $J = \left({-{\pi}} , {\pi}\right)$ then ${{\varphi}}_{r} = {\left.{\varphi}\right|}_{J} \colon  J \rightarrow  {S}_{1} \setminus  \left\{{-1}\right\}$ is a homeomorphism which inverse homeomorphism is given by the map
${{\varphi}}_{r}^{{-1}} \colon  {S}_{1} \setminus  \left\{{-1}\right\} \rightarrow  J$ defined by

$${{\varphi}}_{r}^{{-1}} \left(z\right) = 2 \arcsin  \left(\frac{\Im  \left(z\right)}{\sqrt{2 \left(1+\Re  \left(z\right)\right)}}\right)$$

Let $f$ satisfy the hypothesis of the theorem. Upon replacing $f$ by
${-\frac{f}{f \left({-1}\right)}}$, we may suppose that $f \left({-1}\right) =-1$. Let us define
$g \colon  J \rightarrow  J$ by

$$g = {{\varphi}}_{r}^{{-1}} \circ  f \circ  {{\varphi}}_{r}$$

We see that $g$ is a continuous and one to one real function of one real variable.
It follows that $g$ is monotonic and that $g \left(J\right) = \left(a , b\right)$ is a subinterval
of $J$. Moreover, $a$ and $b$ are the limits (optionally swapped) of $g \left(t\right)$ when $t \rightarrow -{\pi}$ and $t \rightarrow +{\pi}$. Observe that when $t \rightarrow  \pm  {\pi}$
then ${{\varphi}}_{r} \left(t\right) \rightarrow -1$ and $\left({{\varphi}}_{r} \circ  g\right) \left(t\right) = \left(f \circ  {{\varphi}}_{r}\right) \left(t\right) \rightarrow -1$. We conclude
that ${\varphi} \left(g \left(t\right)\right) \rightarrow -1$ and this implies ${e}^{i a} = {e}^{i b} =-1$.

It follows from this that $g \left(J\right) = J$, i.e. $g$ is onto. It follows that
the image of $f \circ  {{\varphi}}_{r} = {{\varphi}}_{r} \circ  g$ is ${S}_{1} \setminus  \left\{{-1}\right\}$, from which we deduce that
$f$ is onto.

To prove that $f$ is an homeomorphism, note that $g$ is an homeomorphism
from $J$ to $J$, and ${f}^{{-1}} \left(z\right) = \left({{\varphi}}_{r} \circ  {g}^{{-1}} \circ  {{\varphi}}_{r}^{{-1}}\right) \left(z\right)$
when $z \neq -1$ and ${f}^{{-1}} \left({-1}\right) =-1$. The result follows easily.

Comment: How do you prove that such curves don't exist in $S^1$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos  If $M(t)$ is such a curve $[0, 2\pi)\to S_1$, I think it is easy to prove that $\theta(t)$ is monotonic by the intermediate value theorem. There are some details with $\theta = 0$ and $\theta = 2\pi$, but it shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: What about $M(t)=e^{it/2}$? It is continuous, non-constant, one to one and not onto.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos but it is not a closed curve. I need $M(t)\to M(0)$ when $t\to 2\pi$.

Comment: I am not so sure that it is easy to prove that no such function can be defined from $S^1$ into $S^1$. Not that I doubt that the statement is true.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos See my edits, it will remove your doubts.

Comment: Yes, it seems to be a complete answer.